# How to use DidEndEditing on textfield on OS X (swift)

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

The thing I want to implement here is after I press the return key, if text of the textfield is match the word January, print right, if not, print wrong.

But when I pressed the return key, Nothing is printed.

Can anyone write a sample code about how to use DidEndEditing for me?

```
@IBOutlet weak var wordTextfield: NSTextField!
let monthEN = "January"

func textFieldDidEndEditing(wordTextfield: NSTextField) {
    if wordTextfield.stringValue == monthE{
        print("right")
    }else{

        print("wrong")
    }
}
```

Comment: There is probably a missing loop in your code... If you want to check against every possible english month (as I understand), then add some loop. Or state your problem more clearly...

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès I added some code on statement. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean "this code doesn't work"?  I'm assuming the method isn't called at all, but you need to add descriptive detail to your question and specify exactly what's "not working".  What is happening?  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @nhgrif when I pressed the return key, Nothing is printed.

Comment: You need to update the question with the details.

Comment: @nhgrif I almost write everything on it. Please help,Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

the textFieldDelegate in os x works like this in Swift 4:

```
class MainViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {

      @IBOutlet weak var textFileViewLabel: NSTextField!

      override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.textField.delegate = self
     }



     override func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
         //Here check the changes of textField input
     }

    override func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
        //Here check the changes of textField input

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you come from an iOS background and you're just now moving into OS X.  I don't have much OS X development experience, but it appears that `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)` is not part of the `NSTextFieldDelegate` protocol.

The `NSTextFieldDelegate` is simply an extension of `NSControlTextEditingDelegate` and adds no methods to it.

And with that in mind, it looks like perhaps we need to implement `control(_:textFieldShouldEndEditing:)` for similar behavior on OS X or potentially `control(_:isValidObject:)`.  But either way, it's important to note that `NSTextField` will never call `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)`--that is strictly from iOS.

For more information, I recommend checking out [the Apple documentation for `NSControlTextEditingDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSControlTextEditingDelegate).

And it's also worth mention to make sure you've actually set the text field's `delegate` property.

Comment: 'func textDidEndEditing(_ notification: NSNotification)' I read the documentation, but I still don't know how to use it, Could you write a sample code for me?

Comment: 1. I don't know what your comment means, but it's different from the code in the question.  2. In order to receive notifications, you must register for notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set the delegate to where the data is (usually to self).
i.e. wordTextfield = self (in ViewDidLoad)